How to display hardware specifications with the terminal?
To display the characteristics of my graphic card, I can use one of these two commands:
 ~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
 ~$ lspci -nnkd ::300

I understand the former but not the latter because of the ::300 part.
I think it must be some kind of identifier for graphic cards but I have no idea where I can find information about this code. If it is a code, which I don't know.
My question is: where can I find information about the meaning of ::300? Or more generally about any ::xxx?

man 8 lspci contains this:

-d [<vendor>]:[<device>][:<class>[:<prog-if>]]

Show only devices with specified vendor, device, class ID, and programming interface. The ID's are given in hexadecimal and may be omitted or given as "*", both meaning "any value". The class ID can contain "x" characters which stand for "any digit".
FILES
/usr/share/misc/pci.ids

A list of all known PCI ID's (vendors, devices, classes and subclasses). Maintained at https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/, use the update-pciids utility to download the most recent version.
/usr/share/misc/pci.ids.gz

If lspci is compiled with support for compression, this file is tried before pci.ids.

And in the (non-compressed) file:

# List of known device classes, subclasses and programming interfaces

# Syntax:
# C class class_name
# subclass    subclass_name       <-- single tab
#     prog-if  prog-if_name   <-- two tabs

[…]
C 03  Display controller
      00  VGA compatible controller
          00  VGA controller
          01  8514 controller
      01  XGA compatible controller
      02  3D controller
      80  Display controller


So it looks that 300 you're asking about is equivalent to 0300, where 03 is for Display controller and 00 is for VGA compatible controller.
Check the file you have in your Linux or download the newest version. The values are there. E.g. -d ::2xx is for network controllers.

I made the answer community wiki because it's basically "read the manual". Frankly I knew nothing about lspci -d until I started trying to answer your question.

thanks to your explanations I now understand what I read in the manual, I didn't even know how to link the -d + :<:class> option to my problem. Now I can see where the "::" comes from.
